# Which file has reference to httpd.conf

Tags: websphere, ibmhttpserver

We are experiencing some problems in our application; our users are automatically getting kicked out of the application. By analyzing the logs we found that the load balancer is switching JVM internally per request. But in the other environments like QA and PERF the session are sticky and hold same JVM.

We have IBM Http server and IBM WebSphere.

We found some errors in the **HTTPServer** logs-error_log- in **DEV** and **TEST**.

```
Using config file : '/usr/HTTPServer/conf//WebAgent.conf'
```

Instead in other environment we found that it the right way- in **QA** and **PERF**

```
Using config file /usr/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf
```

My Question is which file has reference to **httpd.conf**

Comment: webagent.conf is often the siteminder agent conf file. Did that somehow get put in to the IHS configuration in place of httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 2):

The error_log message reflects that someone has changed the "-f" parameter passed to the httpd process.   Using an alternate conf is nothing to be alarmed about.

This usually happens one of two ways.

1. someone edited or wrapped "apachectl" to change the -f parm someone
2. someone passed apachectl -f some-other-conf explicitly (from shell, init script, crontab, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Apache uses httpd.conf. If you see something else (btw, you have a double slash in the wrong path), check the Apache startup script. On BSD this is located in /etc/rc.d but I don't know what OS you are using.

Comment: But I am using IBM HTTP server and thanks pointing out the double slash //

Comment: I just googled it, apparently IBM HTTP also uses http.conf. In that case, check the startup file for the IBM webserver.